# jquery set value of table column span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set the value of a table column span value.  My jQuery looks like this:

```
$('tr td data-th=Name span').val('My span content...');
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td data-th="Name"><span class="edit-input-text"></span>
    <input class="inp input-edit" type="text" name="location_name" value="Shepherds Bush"></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to set the value of the `span` so it looks like this:

`<span class="edit-input-text">My span content...</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

1) attribute value selector for targeting td with attribute value

2) span do not have value attribute. use `.text()` to set the text of span element.

```
$('tr td[data-th=Name] span').text('My span content...');
```